# WordPress plugin special page

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

My plugin makes an interactive image and I want to share it via iframe. Is there a right way to implement a special page with unique url for a wordpress plugin. At the moment I use a page templates, but it's not so friendly. 
I want something like 
www.site.com/myplugin/id=123&param=123 - shows me a special page that renders my plugin in frontend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hook into the [`parse_request`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/parse_request) action before WordPress renders any page like so:

```
function so_46014733( $query ) {
    if (
        isset( $_GET['id'] )
        && isset( $_GET['param'] ) &&
        '123' === $_GET['id'] &&
        '123' === $_GET['param']
    ) {
        include_once 'my_custom_page.html';
        exit;
    }
    return $query;
}
add_action( 'parse_request', 'so_46014733' );
```

A few things to note:

- This will immediately return the default `$query` if the `id` or `param` are empty (almost no performance impact on this check).
- This assumes you want to render your own HTML page (or even a PHP page with your own code) if the `id` and `param` match your keys.
- If you plan to use the `$_GET` variables for anything, be sure to sanitize them first like so:

  `$id = absint( wp_unslash( $_GET['id'] ) );`

Comment: Thanks for answer, I will test this way.